# SSL enabled Content Delivery Network in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, ssl

Building an MVC 2.0 web site and using Content Delivery Network (CDN) in my Site.Master. I’m using the following CDN:

- Yahoo’s reset-fonts-grids.css
- jQuery 1.4.2
- jQuery Validation

All of these CDN are delivered using **http://**

My web site currently supports both SSL and non-SSL pages.
When navigating to SSL enabled pages, I get an error because the CDN are linked to HTTP://

Although I’m aware that you can use an SSL version of CDN but my question is more like:

Since I have non-SSL and SSL pages all sharing **the same** **Site.Master** what should I do?
Should I simply get the SSL enabled version one for both SSL and non-SSL pages? 
Or should I do some kinda of “if…else”?

Any Pros or Cons to any of these approach?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`if`...`else` looks the most viable solution, although you may want to **always** use SSL and forget about everything.

Warnings about pages with mixed-security contents are reasonable, because scripts may be exploitable over insecure connections. Think to a banking website with a hacked script that forwards the HTML markup of your account history to a malicious user.

There is no con in using an `if`-`else` statement to check which protocol string to prepend to the URL of an external resource, not even performance (checks are done in microseconds...), however, about performance, a drawback in always using SSL, while not needed, is present, because the browser will have to establish a secure connection (SSL/TLS handshake) and perform lots of unnecessary cryptographic operations.

I would go for the `if`-`else`, and since you use a master page, you have less places in your code to modify!

Comment: Thanks djechelon! Perhaps I'll got with the If...else approach!
I'm curious...What if instead of using SSL or non-SSL CDN, instead simply add the files in a Folder in my project and link to those files...although it would defeat the purpose of CDN but would it fix my problem as well?

Comment: You said by yourself... it would defeat the CDN's purpose, but, yes, it would fix as relative URLs are correctly mapped to SSL/non-SSL

Comment: there is not point doing that when you can use "//" as the first part of your URL to the CDN if it supports both protocol. No if-else needed. RFCs are useful to read.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, here is the real answer folks. Please read on to enlighten yourselves.

Forget about doing the if else junk you have done in the past for protocol checking BS.

For CDNs supporting SSL such as Amazon Cloudfront or Microsoft CDN, omit the protocol entirely. YES, I said it. Omit the protocol entirely and stop doing if else test. I do this for all my ecommerce websites. The nifty little fact so many people don't know is omitting the protocol forces the URL to use whatever protocol the website URL is using so if you are on SSL, bam, its using SSL, etc. This is actually a web standard and all browsers implement this.

For example, all my CDN image resources and static files etc use URLs like so:

```
<img src="//d34ic8my8k87as.cloudfront.net/img/web/success-icon.png" />
```

If you read RFCs and specifications on the internet, you will find some stuff hiding under your nose. You can see my profile for some sites doing this live. Hope that helps.

Comment: Great answer! RFCs are really useful to read. Unfortunately I have read only those related to Syslog in their entirety :) +1

Comment: Thanks, I used to do if-else for so long myself and accidentally found this fact out looking at an RFC for URLs as I didn't remember what "./" did. SSL then became trivial when using outside resources. This works for Google CDN content as well by the way.